# Multiple If conditions using Iterator in Java

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I have a list which has elements 1 through 10.
I try to remove the prime numbers 2,3,5,7 from it and then print the rest of the list using iterator.But this code throws a  **NoSuchElementException**.
this is my code :

```
public static void editerate2(Collection<Integer> list3)
{
    Iterator<Integer> it=list3.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        if(it.next()==2 || it.next()==3 || it.next() ==5 || it.next()==7 ) 
        {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("List 3:");
    System.out.println("After removing prime numbers  : " + list3);
}
```

What's the correct way of doing this?
Also what's the difference between using "|" and "||" ???

Comment: please include full stacktrace

Comment: Only call `it.next()` once per iteration.

Comment: As for the difference between `|` and `||`, that's a topic for another question- although if you're particularly curious, a google search for "Bitwise Operator" may help you out.

Answer (score 6):

Each time you call `it.next()` your iterator advances to the next element.

This is **NOT** what you want to do I assume.

You should do this in stead:

```
Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    Integer thisInt = it.next();
    if (thisInt == 2 || thisInt == 3 || thisInt == 5 || thisInt == 7) {
       it.remove();
    }
}
```

---

### The difference between | and ||:

If you use `||` and the first part is true, then the 2nd part will not be evaluated.

If you use `|` both parts will always be evaluated.

This is handy for cases like this:

```
if (person == null || person.getName() == null) {
    // do something
}
```

The above snippet would throw a NullPointerException if you used `|` and person was null.

That's because it would evaluate both parts of the condition, and the second half would de-reference a null object.

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid multiple calls to your iterator, as that advances it to the next element.

What you *can* do is preserve the value you get per iteration, then do your comparisons.

```
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Integer next = it.next();
    if(next == 2 || next == 3 || next == 5 || next == 7 ) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```