# Reusing scanner input for multiple conditions in while loop

Tags: java

I would like to use a single scanner input as multiple conditions in while loop where are can check if the input is correct or not and if its not correct to re-enter the input value.

Something like this:

```
while(scannerInput is a int AND scannerInput is > than 0 AND scannerInput is < 10)
{
    //CODE
}
```

but if I use scanner.hasNextInt() and scanner.nextInt() it prompt me for input instead of using the same one

```
while (scaner.hasNextInt() && scaner.nextInt() > 0 && scaner.nextInt() < 10)  {

}
```

Is there a way to store the first input and to re-use it again and again or is there a better solution to my problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple If conditions using Iterator in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831852/multiple-if-conditions-using-iterator-in-java)

Comment: Yes, store it in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call of `scanner.nextInt()` advances the position at which the scanner reads its input, so the second read may produce a different number, or throw an exception when there is only one `int` available. To work around this situation you could introduce a variable to hold the value for the second check:

```
int tmp;
while (scaner.hasNextInt() && (tmp = scaner.nextInt()) > 0 && tmp < 10)  {
    ...
}
```

The second subexpression `(tmp = scaner.nextInt())` reads the next integer value from the `scanner`, and stores it in a temporary variable `tmp`. After that, the value is compared with zero, and finally the same value is compared to 10.

The assignment is performed before the check of `tmp < 10` because parts of `&&` expressions are processed in left to right order.

This solution is not ideal, because `tmp` remains visible after the loop, and because it is not so easy to read. You would be better off moving the check inside the loop, like this:

```
while (scaner.hasNextInt()) {
    int val = scaner.nextInt();
    if (val < 0 || val >= 10) {
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

> My idea was the code to keep prompting you for new input until its correct

A common way to achieve this is with a `do`/`while` loop:

```
int val = -1;
do {
    System.out.print("Enter an int: ");
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        val = scanner.nextInt();
    } else {
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
} while (val < 0 || val >= 10);
```

Comment: Yes but in this case I wont be propted direcrtly to type in new input, I will have to navigate back to this method, my idea was the code to keep prompting you for new input until its correct

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
int s;
while (scanner.hasNext() && (s = scanner.nextInt()) >0 && s <0){
 #code          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some options here.

1. You could put an if condition inside the while and give while a true as condition.. let the if statement break the while loop
2. you could write a method which does the checks and give scanner.nextInt() as parameter